# angular2, Set Custom Validation in blur

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I need to set Custom Validator in Blur event. Is there any other option to set 
   validation in blur instead of touched,

```
<div
*ngIf="firstname.dirty && !firstname.valid && firstname.value!='' && 
firstname.touched" class="cmsg">
        <p *ngIf="firstname.errors.alphaValidator">Invalid Format</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not put a `[(ngModel)]` on your `firstname` input element

And then subscribe to your model for changes in order to validate, it should catch the `blur` event also.

Answer (score 0):

Already I added [(ngModel)] in my Element.

```
<input type="text" ngControl="firstname" [(ngModel)]="FirstName">
```

But I need to set Validation Controls in Blur Condition instead of 'touching'.